# Open Orbit of a group action

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, terminology, group-actions

I have come across the term "open orbit" in the context of group theory but I don't quite understand what it means.

Does it mean one orbit forms a set that is topologically open?

What is the significance for the group/set when the action has an open orbit?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the meaning.

Comment: In what context did you read this? What were you proving or reading? If we know more about your exact situation we can help you with the significance.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor e.g. Popov, Vladimir L. "Generically multiple transitive algebraic group actions." arXiv preprint math/0409024 (2004).